# Post Parameters are missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

So I am posting some parameters to a .NET website.  The website requires authentication, so it redirects the user to a login page.  If the action contains the login page, then the post parameters come through, but if the action does not contain the login page, the post parameters don't come through.

```
<form action="http://localhost:54060/mywebsite/" method="post">
    BAC: <input type="text" name="partnerID" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="partnerType" value="test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="test" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="test" />
</form>
```

I am capturing the post parameters in the Session_Start Global asax page event and pulling them by using: `this.Request.Params["partnerID"]`.  This is empty if the call is made like above, but contains the parameters if the login page is included in the action.

Note: The form sits in 1 website and is being submitting to a different website.  These sit on different servers.  I do not have control of the website that is submitting the form (and submitting it to a iframe).  I do have control over the .NET website that is receiving the form submit.

Why are these parameters not coming through when the form is submitted to the website instead of being submitted to the page.

Comment: What submit's this form? I don't see a submit button...

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Ok, I remove it, something I miss...

Answer (score 1):

Method `Session_Start` executes only once: when your session starts ;) So, next time you access the same page (or any page), the method won't execute because you already have the session. When you post-back from your page `Session_Start` will not execute, because it executed when the page was rendered, if that was your first page.

If you really must handle the submitted values in Global.asax, then use `Application_BeginRequest`. However, I think it should be done in some other way, i.e. have your form submit always to a particular page where you handle the values that get ppassed in.

Comment: The form is being submitted from another website.  So this would be the correct place because it will be executing when the request is coming in from the form.